# Php artisan schedule dosen't execute the command

Tags: php, laravel

so I'am trying to run a task with laravel schedule and php schedule:run works well but it does not execute the command in real

There is my kernel class

```
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //

    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        //$schedule->exec('php artisan migrate:fresh')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('migrate:fresh')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

And the result of php schedule:run

```
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.2' artisan migrate:fresh > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

Comment: Did you set in your `.env` to use database driver?

Comment: Yes, i'am using docker images and when i execute php artisan migrate:fresh without the schedule it works

Comment: Have you created a cron job to run 'php artisan schedule:run' every minute?

Comment: No, i run it manually

Comment: try adding --force after your command migtration comands are a bit tricky.

Comment: @MoubarakHayal like this : $schedule->command('migrate:fresh --force')->everyMinute(); ?

Comment: Are you sure the command is not executed? Have you checked if your database is actually refreshed?

Comment: yes like that.it will force artisan to make the call.

Comment: Thank you! it worked for me with --force. And by the way i have to do some tests on my database every x time, so what's the best way to do it? create a controller and call it from the schedule or do the test in commands folder ?

Comment: @Gavroch in my opinion that's the perfect case for a command.  See the comments on my answer for a bit more detail.

Comment: To run a controller in scheduler $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\yourController@index')->everyMinute() incase you go with that route

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a CRON job to run scheduler every minute.

The CRON will then automatically fire every minute and run whatever command you set in the kernel->schedule function.

You can find the details in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) under Starting The Scheduler

Comment: Thank you! it worked for me with --force, i think because there's a control of yes when we try to migrate! and by the way i had another question could we call a controller from schedule?

Comment: Never tried it but I don't see why not, a controller is just a class at the end of the day.  But in my opinion the best and cleanest way is to create a custom command which does the logic rather than the controller.  Then use scheduler to run your custom command.  Try to keep the Kernal as clean as possible so try not to enter business logic.  Look at this link for commands https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#writing-commands

Comment: Should have also added that by creating a command you can run it at anytime on the CLI and not just when scheduled.  So for instance I have a command that cleans out a database table which runs every month.  But if its getting a bit full I can just jump on the command line and run a command to clear it.